# How to clone HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

Let's say we receive an `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
void Process(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage;
    newRequest.Content = request.Content; //are the Content properties pointing to the same memory location??

    //do stuff
}
```

**If I mutate `request.Content`, will `newRequest.Content` be affected as well?**

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044166/how-to-clone-a-httprequestmessage-when-the-original-request-has-content

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467018/how-to-forward-an-httprequestmessage-to-another-server